# Missing dependencies in war. Gradle build project

Tags: java, gradle, war

I've a war project build by gradle.
And I've a string in gradle.build file: `compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'`
But thereis no any log4j.jar in resulting WEB-INF/lib directory in myproject.war file.

But all other libs defined in "compile" configuration are there.
Why so strange behaviour, is it a bug or some kind of feature? And how to include it in my webarchive?

Eclipse shows log4j.jar in "web app libraries" part of the project.
I'm using gradle v. 2.3 from Eclipse and console.

Comment: How are you building the WAR file?

Comment: "gradle build" from eclipse and windows console

Comment: It might help to include the relevant parts of your gradle.build file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a `providedCompile 'anotherproject'` dependency, which contains log4j, and blocks it in dependent module.

Answer (score 0):

have you applied `eclipse-wtp`. I think `eclipse-wtp` needs to be applied to all projects, including the root project if you have multiple projects.

My [reference](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/eclipse-war-project-missing-dependencies/6220) to the answer.

Comment: I think the OP has the opposite problem - in Eclipse it's fine but the WAR is incomplete

Comment: oppss...my bad.@MrWiggles